# Responses returning truncated with llma_index

Tags: python, openai-api

```
 import os
 import logging
 from llama_index import GPTSimpleVectorIndex
 from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
 os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = 'sk-......'


 message_history = [{"role": "user", "content": f"You are a Assistan! Answer every 
 question in Assitant!"},
               {"role": "assistant", "content": f"OK"}]
def chatbot(input_text):
    # Load the pre-created index
    index = GPTSimpleVectorIndex.load_from_disk('index.json')
    message_history.append({"role": "user", "content": f"{input_text}"})
    # Get a response for the user's question
    response = index.query(input_text, response_mode="compact")

    return response.response


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    while True:
        user_input = input("\nquestion (çıkmak için 'exit' yazın): ")
        if user_input.lower() == 'exit':
            break
        response = chatbot(user_input)
        print("\nAnswer:", response)
```

Hello,

I am trying the llma_index with the code I shared above, but my responses always come truncated. I tried splitting the response first and then rejoining it to avoid exceeding the token limit, but there was no improvement. I would be very grateful if you could help.